# Java and file list

Tags: java, file-io, io

I should get a list of file contained in a directory.

What I do is:

```
    File file = new File(PATH);
    for (File index:file.listFiles)
        System.out.println(index.toString());
```

The matter is that doing this I get printed also files I shouldn't see, temporary, for example.

In my test directory I have to file: *ciao* and *test*, but when I run my code I see *ciao*, *ciao~*, *test~*, and also other stuff if I modify a file (I suppose they are buffer file).

So, how can I get only *true* file, as if I was browsing my fileSystem?

Comment: Even temporary files are true files, what makes you think they are not?

Comment: as a mattter of fact i wrote it in italic and I specified I only need file are listed when I browse my directory with Nautilus.

Comment: Try `index.isHidden()` if you meant to check for hidden files; I'm not quite sure what distinguishes these 'temporary' files so that you don't see them in Nautilus.

Comment: @praseodym under Unix that would be files beginning with a dot.

Comment: @fge yes; I meant that I didn't understand what the OP thought distinguishes the files he did not want to see because they are clearly not hidden under Unix.

Comment: @praseodym yes, hence the usefulness of `FileFilter` in such a case ;)

Comment: @litiales You should start by defining what files you *want* to see. Or alternatively, you can define what files you *don't* want to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to list only files whose attributes (name included) obey a set of conditions, you need to use another version of `.listFiles()` which takes a `FileFilter` as an argument. This interface has a sole `accept()` method which returns true if the file can be listed.

This simple example will filter out files whose name end with a `~`:

```
file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return !pathname.getName().endsWith("~");
    }
})
```

If your `FileFilter` is more complex than the one above, consider exernalizing it to a variable (`private static final` if the filter will never change).

Comment: nice, guy. fully implemented, nothing more to think for the asking one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
if (!index.isHidden()) {
    System.out.println(index.toString());
}
```

to suppress hidden files.

you further can check for

```
index.isDirectory()
```

if you dont want subdirectory to be listed.

But dont expect an method that can read your thougts what you call an real (or clean, or nice) file.

You could write yourself a filter for that, once you now what files to exclude.

See `java.io.FileFilter` for more.

Answer (score 1):

Files you don't see are probably hidden, you can check that:

```
File file = ...;
if(file.isHidden()){...}
```